# Kohana ORM Pivot Table Wrong Data

Tags: php, orm, kohana, pivot-table

I have Users, Categories, and Posts. Users has many Posts, Categories has many Posts, Posts belongs to one Category and one User.

I need help displaying the correct User with the correct Post.

Tables

```
categories{category_id, category_title}
posts{post_id, post_title}
users{user_id, user_title}
categories_posts{category_id, post_id}
users_posts{user_id, post_id}
```

Models

```
class Model_User extends ORM {

protected $_primary_key = 'user_id';

protected $_has_many = array(
    'posts'=> array(
        'model' => 'post',                
        'through' => 'users_posts',   
        'far_key' => 'post_id'        
    ),
  );
}

class Model_Category extends ORM {

    protected $_primary_key = 'category_id';

    protected $_has_many = array(
    'posts'=> array(
        'model' => 'post',                
        'through' => 'categories_posts',   
        'far_key' => 'post_id'           
    )
  );
}

class Model_Post extends ORM {

    protected $_primary_key = 'post_id';

    protected $_belongs_to = array(
    'categories'=> array(
        'model' => 'category',               
        'through' => 'categories_forums',  
        'far_key' => 'category_id'  
    ),

    'users'=> array(
        'model' => 'user',                
        'through' => 'users_posts',    
        'far_key' => 'user_id'   
    )
  );
}
```

Display

```
$categories = ORM::factory('category')->find_all(); 
foreach ($categories as $category) :
echo $category->category_title;
foreach ($category->posts->find_all() as $post) :
echo $post->post_title;
echo $post->users->user_title;
endforeach;
endforeach;
```

Categories and Posts echos correctly, but Users does not.

Lets say users_posts has the following:

```
user_id post_id
1      1
1      2
1      3
2      4
```

The code above will echo User One, User Two, NULL, NULL instead of User One, User One, User One, User Two. For some reason it matches Post One with User One and Post Two with User Two because they have the same id numbers.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is what is suppose to echo:

```
Category One
Post One
User One
Post Two
User One

Category Two
Post Three
User One
Post Four
User Two
```

Here is what the code echos:

```
Category One
Post One
User One
Post Two
User Two

Category Two
Post Three
NULL
Post Four
NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only really need to use a pivot table when you need to track many-to-many relationship, and in this scenario there are no many-to-many relationships to track (just one-to-many relationships).

As a start, Post model should have fields `user_id` and `category_id` as foreign keys to track the one-to-many relationships. The documentation explains how you should construct your models, with the users, categories, posts example (almost exactly the same as what you're trying to achieve): 
http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/orm/relationships